# how can I plot choropleth map from attribute of shapefile?

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

I want to make a choropleth map from joined csv file. I joined CSV to shapefile and I am able to create a barchart but cannot show the attribute in achoropleth map.

```
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(tmap)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
tmap_mode("plot")

setwd("C:/Users/ITLINK/Desktop/unigis/environmental monitooring")
Bagmati_shp<- readOGR(dsn="BagmatiProvinance.shp")
wasteDEPOSIT<- read.csv("C:/Users/ITLINK/Desktop/unigis/environmental 
monitooring/solid_waste.csv")
Bagmati_shp@data<- left_join(Bagmati_shp@data, wasteDEPOSIT, by= c ('DISTRICT' = 'dist_name'))
head(Bagmati_shp)
barplot(Bagmati_shp@data$WSHED, ylim=c(0,10000),names = Bagmati_shp@data$DISTRICT, xlab= 
"DISTRICT", ylab="Waste deposit", main="waste deposit in Bagmati provinance")
```

Comment: can you provide a [mcve]? For example, using the shapefiles referred to here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf2.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please edit your question into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier for others to help?